# “Win streak” vs “winning streak”

Tags: grammaticality

Does context have a role to play in determining which is used?
Ie: upon research I’ve found that various sport-news outlets tend use “win streak” more often...

My example: “...build a win/winning streak” — in an internet application context.

Comment: Are the news outlets you refer to American? I don't recognise "win streak" as a part of British English at all.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a less common variant than [winning streak:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak)

> ***A winning streak, a.k.a. a win streak or hot streak,*** is an uninterrupted sequence of success in games or competitions, commonly measured by wins that are uninterrupted by losses or ties/draws. In sports, it can be applied to teams, and individuals.

(Wikipedia)

See also [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=win%20streak%2Cwinning%20streak&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwin%20streak%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwin%20streak%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWin%20Streak%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWIN%20STREAK%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwinning%20streak%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwinning%20streak%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWinning%20Streak%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWINNING%20STREAK%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'd say 'win streak' is a relative newcomer, part of the gradual conquest of premodification by the attributive noun.

Comment: The tendency of publications to use the shortest possible words in headlines might apply: "win streak" saves a few characters and a bit of paper or screen space.